Reference request for a Lemma used by Sacks
In the answer to this question: Turing degrees that eventually jump to some $0^{(n)}$ a paper by Sacks is linked https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-01/S0002-9939-1967-0207558-7/S0002-9939-1967-0207558-7.pdf. The proof in the paper is surprisingly nice except it makes use of a lemma, namely that there exists a computable function $t$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
\forall A\subseteq \omega \;\forall e\in \omega\;(A<_T R^A_{t(e)} <_T A' \wedge (R^A_{t(e)})'=R^{A'}_e) 
\end{equation*}
Where $R^X_e=X\oplus W^X_e$ and $W^X_e$ is the $e$-th $X$ c.e. set. Sacks states that this statement follows from Theorem 6.3 of his book degrees of unsolvability. However, the proof is 20 pages long and uses some difficult notation. I would appreciate any more recent reference or a sketch of the proof.
